# Sub-select in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select the newest price from another table in a sub select. But I can't figure out how to get it working.

This is what I've tried:

```
select something, somthingelse, 
  (
    select * from 
    (
      select QUOTE_PRICE as old_price
      from price_history
      where price_history.part_no= article_table.part_no
      order by valid_from desc
    ) where rownum=1
  )
from  article_table where rownum < 5
```

The subselect works by itself, but it can't find `article_table.part_no`:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "article_table "."part_no": invalid identifier

**Update:**

Current solution:

```
select something, somethingelse, (
  SELECT MIN(QUOTE_PRICE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY valid_from)
  FROM price_history
  WHERE part_no=article_table.part_no
) as old_price
from  article_table a where rownum < 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Oracle, subqueries can only see values from parent queries one level deep. Since you have two nested selects the inner one can't see the values from the outer one.

You could perform the join first:

```
SELECT something, somthingelse, old_price
  FROM (SELECT a.something, a.somthingelse, p.quote_price old_price,
               row_number() over (PARTITION BY a.part_no 
                                  ORDER BY valid_from DESC) rnk
           FROM article_table a
           LEFT JOIN price_history p ON a.part_no = p.part_no)
 WHERE rnk = 1;
```

You could also use a PL/SQL function that would return the first `quote_price` from `price_history` when given a `article_table.part_no`.

Comment: Wont work. I do not want to select only one row. I want to get the previous price for all rows in article_table. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: @jgauffin : Run the query :) -- the query will return one row per `article_table` row.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks. +1. What do you think of the solution that I added to my question?

Comment: @jgauffin: it's a nice workaround of the "one-level-deep" limitation. It forces a kind of nested loop join (conceptually: fetch one row, get the max from the other table, fetch next row...) so it performs really fast if you don't fetch lots of rows from `article_table` (in your case it probably is the best method since you return only 5 rows). In case of large datasets, performing the join first allows the optimizer to choose from a larger set of access paths which may result in more efficient plan (in particular hash joins).

Comment: isn't `first_value()` what you want instead of `row_number() ... where = 1 `?

Comment: @Benoit: [`first_value`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions057.htm#i83212) would return N rows per row in `article_table` (where N is the number of `price_history` rows for this `part_no`). Each of the N rows would have the same old_price so you would need to dedup them somehow. You could do it with a DISTINCT, still I think the RANK method is easier to read -- I use `row_number` because I don't know if `(part_no, valid_from)` is unique in `price_history`.

Answer (score 2):

Try aliasing `article_table` in the outermost query:

```
select a.something, a.somthingelse, 
  (
    select * from 
    (
      select QUOTE_PRICE as old_price
      from price_history
      where price_history.part_no= a.part_no
      order by valid_from desc
    ) where rownum=1
  )
from  article_table a where rownum < 5
```

Besides, you might want to look into Oracle analytic functions to make simpler queries for that kind of purpose:

http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html

Comment: I asked for an undelete of your answer since the link to the analytical functions help med to the solution in my updated answer. I would accepted it if I hadn't got a cleaner solution. Don't be so quick at deleting answers.

Comment: As you wish... :-) I thought the main answer was wrong and the analytic functions were proposed by someone else too, so my answer is misleading for other readers...

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

```
select something, somethingelse, last_value(quote_price) over (partition by part_no order by valid_from asc)
  from article_table inner join price_history using (part_no)
 where rownum < 5;
```