# 2 max statements in one Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, max

Is there a way of having Oracle bring back the max value for 2+ fields in one SQL query?

I have code to search for all instances of "ID38" in the notes field, then bring back the highest job_log_number with "ID38" in it.

This however might not be the final status on the job.  So I would like to create another column to bring back the highest job_log_number value on the job, regardless of whether it contains "ID38" or not.

Existing Code:

```
select
j1.job_number,
job_status_log.log_text,
job_status_log.job_log_number


from
job j1
inner join job_status_log on j1.job_number = job_status_log.job_number

where

job_status_log.job_log_number =
(select max (job_status_log.job_log_number)
from
job j2
inner join job_status_log on j2.job_number = job_status_log.job_number
where j1.job_number = j2.job_number and
job_status_log.log_text LIKE '%to Tree Team 1 (ID38)%')

order by 
j1.job_number, job_status_log.job_log_number
```

Current Results

```
Job Number         Log Text         Log Number
123                 ID38                 3
193                 ID38                 4
392                 ID38                 1
```

What I would like to end up with is

```
Job Number         Log Text         Log Number         Highest Log Number On Job
123                 ID38                 3                        3
193                 ID38                 4                        5
392                 ID38                 1                        4
```

Comment: You can accomplish that with "subselection" or a "subselect" statement.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740813/sub-select-in-oracle

Comment: Thank you - have added subquery to the main select section and this has accomplished what I was after.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read. (And to write...)