# Joining 2 SQL Queries Together

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following 2 separate SQL queries which I need to join together:

```
SELECT SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE, CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date
FROM CUSTOMER 
where processing_date ='08-JAN-24'
order by loan_size desc;
```

and

```
SELECT SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO,APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,APPLICATION_ID,DT_OUTCOME,
row_number() over (partition by SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO order by APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE desc) as rank
from ACCOUNT;
```

Both queries work fine on their own, but I am struggling to work out how to successfully join the 2 queries together to produce results.

I have attempted the following:

```
SELECT SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE, CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date
FROM CUSTOMER
where processing_date ='08-JAN-24'
order by loan_size desc
inner join ACCOUNT on CUSTOMER.SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO = ACCOUNT.SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO;
```

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

and

```
SELECT SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO, COLLATERAL_ID, LOAN_SIZE, CURRENT_BALANCE, processing_date
FROM CUSTOMER 
full outer join ACCOUNT
on CUSTOMER.SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO = ACCOUNT.SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO
where processing_date ='08-JAN-24'
order by loan_size desc;
```

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated as my SQL knowledge is severely limited to the basic level of query writing.

Comment: Without looking or knowing anything about oracle, `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` means you have multiple columns of the same name. To get around this you might refer to such columns by their full name, i.e. including the table name. This can be made easier by using table aliases (may even be necessary if you’re using the same table twice). Also, in your first attempt you’re trying to use a `join` clause outside of the `from` block – never tell anyone about that one.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741338

Comment: Note that join conditions with concatenation involved is tricky. 1) You'll probably miss index usage. 2) `'ab' || 'cd' = 'abc' || 'd'`, which might return more rows than desired.

Comment: The c.processing_date condition in the WHERE clause makes the FULL OUTER JOIN return LEFT OUTER JOIN result. If you want a true FULL OUTER JOIN result, move that condition to the ON clause. (And if you want a LEFT JOIN result, do a LEFT JOIN.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to join 2 working queries (keeping in mind all remarks from MTO's answer) - you can do it like below, but you should decide what kind of join to use (Inner, Left, Full, ...) depending on your data and what do you want to get as a result. We don't know your context.
Anyway, here is the code that joins your 2 working queries selecting columns from both of them:

```sql
--  ... your first working query 
Select      -- c.SORT_CODE || c.ACCOUNT_NO "CODE_ACCTNO", 
            c.SORT_CODE, c.ACCOUNT_NO   -- if using the line above then comment out this one
            c.COLLATERAL_ID, 
            c.LOAN_SIZE, 
            c.CURRENT_BALANCE, 
            c.PROCESSING_DATE,
            --  above is selection from 1st (c.) and below from 2nd (a.) query  
            a.APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,
            a.APPLICATION_ID,
            a.DT_OUTCOME, 
            a.RN
From        CUSTOMER  c
            -- below is your second working query (changed RANK to RN since RANK is reserved word)
Inner Join  ( Select    -- SORT_CODE || ACCOUNT_NO "CODE_ACCNO"
                        SORT_CODE, ACCOUNT_NO,   -- if using the line above then you may (but not have to) comment out this one
                        APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,
                        APPLICATION_ID,
                        DT_OUTCOME, 
                        Row_Number() Over (Partition By SORT_CODE||ACCOUNT_NO Order By APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE Desc) "RN" 
             From ACCOUNT
            ) a ON( a.SORT_CODE = c.SORT_CODE And a.ACCOUNT_NO = c.ACCOUNT_NO ) 
          -- if concatenated in both selection lists then  --> ) a ON( c.SORT_CODE || c.ACCOUNT_NO = a.CODE_ACCNO )
Where      c.PROCESSING_DATE = DATE '2024-01-08'
Order By   c.LOAN_SIZE
```

Comment: Thanks for responding d r, much appreciated!!  One slight issue with the above in that the alias of ACCOUNT doesn't seem to work, as I'm getting the below error when attempting to execute:

ORA-00904: "A"."ACCOUNT_NO": invalid identifier

Not requesting a fix/response here, but just letting you know out of courtesy.  Thanks again

Comment: @Neal It doesn't work because the inner-joined `SELECT` concatenates the `SORT_CODE` and `ACCOUNT_NO` into a single composite value called `CODE_ACCTNO`. Don't concatenate the values together; leave them as `SORT_CODE` and `ACCOUNT_NO` in the inner-most select and then those columns will exist for the join condition to use.

Comment: @Neal Fixed as in MTO's comment (thanks). My fault. You can't join on columns not in select list. Other way to do it would be concatinated columns in selection lists and in join's ON clause.

Answer (score 2):

- The order of clauses is `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`. All the tables you select `FROM` need to be listed in the `FROM` clauses with their `JOIN` conditions.
- Use aliases for the tables and prefix the column identifiers with the aliases.

Your first query doesn't work because you have a `JOIN` in the `ORDER BY` clause, and not the `FROM` clause.

Your second query does not work because the `CUSTOMER` and `ACCOUNT` tables both have a `SORT_CODE` and an `ACCOUNT` column and the SQL engine does not know which table you are trying to get the information from, so you need to tell it by using the table identifiers/aliases.

```
SELECT c.SORT_CODE||c.ACCOUNT_NO,
       c.COLLATERAL_ID,
       c.LOAN_SIZE,
       c.CURRENT_BALANCE,
       c.processing_date
FROM   CUSTOMER c
       INNER JOIN ACCOUNT a
       ON     c.SORT_CODE  = a.SORT_CODE
          AND c.ACCOUNT_NO = a.ACCOUNT_NO
WHERE  c.processing_date = DATE '2024-01-08'
ORDER BY c.loan_size DESC;
```

If you want the additional columns from the second query then:

```
SELECT c.SORT_CODE||c.ACCOUNT_NO,
       c.COLLATERAL_ID,
       c.LOAN_SIZE,
       c.CURRENT_BALANCE,
       c.processing_date
       a.APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,
       a.APPLICATION_ID,
       a.DT_OUTCOME,
       a.rank
FROM   CUSTOMER c
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT a.SORT_CODE,
                a.ACCOUNT_NO,
                a.APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,
                a.APPLICATION_ID,
                a.DT_OUTCOME,
                row_number() over (
                  partition by a.SORT_CODE, a.ACCOUNT_NO
                  order by a.APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE desc
                ) as rank
         from   ACCOUNT a
       ) a
       ON     c.SORT_CODE  = a.SORT_CODE
          AND c.ACCOUNT_NO = a.ACCOUNT_NO
WHERE  c.processing_date = DATE '2024-01-08'
ORDER BY c.loan_size DESC;
```

or:

```
SELECT c.SORT_CODE||c.ACCOUNT_NO,
       c.COLLATERAL_ID,
       c.LOAN_SIZE,
       c.CURRENT_BALANCE,
       c.processing_date
       a.APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE,
       a.APPLICATION_ID,
       a.DT_OUTCOME,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         partition by c.SORT_CODE, c.ACCOUNT_NO
         order by a.APPLICATION_CREATED_DATE desc
       ) AS rank
FROM   CUSTOMER c
       INNER JOIN ACCOUNT a
       ON     c.SORT_CODE  = a.SORT_CODE
          AND c.ACCOUNT_NO = a.ACCOUNT_NO
WHERE  c.processing_date = DATE '2024-01-08'
ORDER BY c.loan_size DESC;
```

*Note: Do not concatenate `SORT_CODE` and `ACCOUNT_NO` into a single string until you want to display it in the outer-most `SELECT` clause (and maybe not then as that concatenation is better left to the middle-tier or client application as to how it wants to display the individual values to the client).*

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response MTO, much appreciated.